# Weird icons appearing on Safari in between words

Tags: html, css, safari, icons

I'm seeing strange icons on Safari, but only in one section of my site, I've tried googling/searching stack for an answer but it's hard because I can't copy the symbols and in the inspector there's just space between each word. The only way I can show the problem is with a picture:

[image]

Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: Possibly trying to load a character type it can't recognise?

Comment: Have you tried to manually delete each space between the words, and then update, to see if the characters are gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your browser is using a different character encoding from that of the document you're viewing.

So be sure that your web page uses the UTF-8 encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It was photoshop's fault, I'd copied the text straight from the PSD and I guess it had some encoding that added those symbols, I've re-typed the quote by hand (shudder) and the symbols are gone :)